# Не работает часть функции после установки плагина vuex-persistedstate

Tags: vue.js, vuex

После установки плагина vuex-persistedstate при перезагрузки страницы как бы ломает функцию.

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        products: []
        },
    getters: {
        products(state){
            return state.products;
        },
        test(state){
            return state.test;
        },
        totalCount(state){
            let total = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i<state.products.length; i++){
                total += state.products[i].count;
                state.products[i].sum = state.products[i].count*state.products[i].price;
            }
            return total;
        },
        totalPrice(state){
            let total = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i<state.products.length; i++){
                total += state.products[i].sum;
            }
            return total;
        }

    },

    mutations: {
        add(state, product){
            if(state.products.indexOf(product) === -1){
                state.products.unshift(product);
            }
            else {
                let pos = state.products.indexOf(product);
                state.products[pos].count++;
            }
        },
        removeFromCart(state, product){
            let pos = state.products.indexOf(product);
            state.products[pos].count = 1;
            state.products.splice(pos, 1);

        },
        removeAll(state){
            for(let i = 0; i<state.products.length; i++){
                state.products[i].count = 1;
            }
            state.products = [];
        },
        minus(state, product){
            if(state.products.indexOf(product) !== -1 && state.products[state.products.indexOf(product)].count > 1){
                let pos = state.products.indexOf(product);
                state.products[pos].count--;
                    }
                },
        onInput(state, payload){
            let pos = state.products.indexOf(payload.product);
            state.products[pos].count = parseInt(payload.value);


        }
    },
    actions: {
        add(store, product){
            store.commit('add', product);
        },
        removeFromCart(store, product){
            store.commit('removeFromCart', product);
        },
        removeAll(store){
            store.commit('removeAll');
        },
        minus(store, product){
            store.commit('minus', product);
        }
    }
};




<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Продукты</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-4" 
                 v-for="product in products">
                 <img :src="product.image" alt="">
                 <router-link tag="h3" :to="'/products/' + product.id_product">
                    <a>{{ product.title }}</a>
                </router-link>
                <div>{{ product.price }}</div>
                <button @click="addToCart(product)"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        >
                    Add to cart
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex';

    export default {

        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('products', {
                products: 'items'
            }),
            ...mapGetters('cart', {
                inCart: 'products'
            })
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('cart', {
                addToCart: 'add'
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

До установки если в корзине не было товара, он добавлял товар, если товар есть, то срабатывает счетчик кол-ва. После плагина, товар дублируется после перезагрузки

Вот здесь кол-во товаров поле count завязано на две кнопки и инпут

```
  <tr v-for="product in productsInCart">
                            <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ product.price }} руб.</td>
                            <td style="display: flex;">
                                <span>{{ product.count }}</span>
                                <span>x</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" 
                                    @click="minus(product)"
                            >-1</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" 
                                    @click="plus(product)">+1</button>
                                     <input type="text" 
                                            :value="product.count"
                                            @input="onInput($event, product)"
                                            >
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-size:18px">{{ product.sum }} руб.</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger"
                                        @click="remove(product)"
                            >
                        Удалить
                    </button></td>
                        </tr>

    methods: {
                ...mapActions('cart', {
                    remove: 'removeFromCart',
                    removeAll:'removeAll',
                    plus:'add',
                    minus:'minus'
                }),
                onInput(e, product){
                    this.$store.commit('cart/onInput', {
                        value: e.target.value,
                        product: product
                    });
                }

            }
    }
```

в store

```
 mutations: {
    onInput(state, payload){
                let index = state.products.indexOf(payload.product);
                state.products[index].count = payload.value;


            }
    }
```

Comment: расширьте пример, покажите как вы вызываете мутацию, ваш стейт и тд..

Comment: Расширил в первоначальном вопросе

Comment: Обновил код в вопросе

Comment: извините, я может не до конца понимаю вашу проблему, но если вы удаляете товар - он удаляется вообще из массива и естественным образом он пропадает из шаблона `v-for`, а что именно сохраняется?

Comment: В том то и дело, что товар из массива удаляется, но потом снова при добавлении свойство count переопределяется на значение, которые было в value перед удалением, именно потому, я перед удалением товара count ставил в 1, чтобы value переопределилось, так там двунаправленная связь

Comment: Хотя я не понимаю почему после удаления это value где то в памяти сохраняется....

Comment: Вообщем с value я разобрался, а вот плагин все равно дублирует мне товар после перезагрузки(

Comment: да, а на какой номер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев ваши мутации есть несколько замечаний.

Первая мутация `add`:

```
add(state, product) {
    const index = state.products.indexOf(product);

    if (index === -1) {
        state.products = [product, ...state.products];
    } else {
        state.products[index].count += 1;
    }
}
```

Реактивность `vue` против использования мутаций массива с использованием `push | pop | shift | unshift`, переопределяйте ссылку. Далее никогда не инкрементируйте какое-то свойство в объекте через `++`, используйте `+= 1`.

Вторая мутация `removeFromCart`:

```
removeFromCart(state, product) {
    // вот здесь непонятно, вы изменяете свойство
    // а потом делаете `splice`
    const index = state.products.indexOf(product);
    // опять же избегаем мутации через `splice`
    state.products = state.products.filter((product) => {
        return product !== state.products[index];
    });
}
```

Третья мутация `minus`, избегаем декремента через `--`:

```
minus(state, product) {
    const index = state.products.indexOf(product);

    if (index === -1 || state.products[index].count <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    state.products[index] -= 1;
}
```

Сразу вам говорю, что проблема не в плагине `vuex-persistedstate` и он ничего не ломает, вы можете посмотреть его исходник в `node_modules`, все, что он делает это `localStorage.setItem` и `localStorage.getItem`.

Мутация `removeAll` тоже не совсем понятна, вы тут в цикле изменяете свойство, а потом переопределяете ссылку на пустой массив:

```
removeAll(state) {
    for(let i = 0; i < state.products.length; i++){
        state.products[i].count = 1;
    }

    state.products = [];
}
```

Comment: У меня поле count еще завязано на input и получается, если удаляешь один товар или все сразу, значения из инпутов где то сохраняется и получается, что когда опять добавляешь товар  - поле count сохранено от значения инпута....Поэтому я перед удалением одного товара или всех свожу поле count к единице

Comment: Как же тогда добавлять товар в массив? Использовать тогда объект вместо массива и добавлять через $set?

Comment: нет, `$set` вообще не нужно использовать, я же вам написал мутацию `add` :-)

Comment: А как бороться с тем, что после удаления товара, свойство count сохраняется из value инпута?

Comment: где сам инпут и где именно сохраняется свойство `count`?